# For TileItem DevExpress - by default we have text aligned at upper left corner. Need to align the text to lower right corner and also put a icon

Tags: devexpress

[Tile Expected UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vixqQ.png)

The effect needed is as mentioned in the image shown
We have DevExpress Control TileItem. And we want the text to be displayed at the lower left corner and also need to put an icon in lower right corner

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the corresponding [TextAlignment](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileItemElement_TextAlignmenttopic)/[ImageToTextAlignment](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileItemElement_ImageToTextAlignmenttopic) properties:

```
tileItemElement1.Text = "My Tile Item Text";
tileItemElement1.TextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItemContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
tileItemElement1.Image = /* some image */;
tileItemElement1.ImageToTextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControlImageToTextAlignment.Right;
```

Related help topic: [Tile Item Structure](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10986)